# range validator disallowing some values within range

Tags: asp.net, rangevalidator

I have a textbox with a range validator that is acting odd:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="hoursInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rangeValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="hoursInput" MaximumValue="200" MinimumValue="0" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="!!!" />
```

As you can see my goal is to allow the range 0-200 however the values 3-99 are causing the error message to go off and prevent the user from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

give the Type as Integer in your RangeValidator

```
<asp:RangeValidator  Type=Integer  ....
```